# Rspec Rails setting a value in a JSON object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I am writing a test for a method in my application_controller.rb and having trouble writing a proper test. The app is built on Rails 3.2.17.

**object.rb**

```
def previously_purchased?
  return JSON.parse(self.features)['key']['previously_purchased'] if self.features
end
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
def include_bar?
  url_param = params[:keyword] || cookies[:keyword]
  @keyword_object = Object.find_by_url(url_param)
    if @keyword_object.previously_purchased? && !cookies[:prior_purchase] 
      @keyword_object = nil
      return
    end
end
```

**factories.rb**

```
factory: object do
  url_param 'TEST'
end
```

**application_controller_spec.rb**

```
#this was the most recent test I tried

context 'URL parameter keyword is present or keyword cookie is present' do
  context 'object is displayed only to previously purchased' do
    before(:each) do
      @saved_object = create :object
      @other_object = JSON.parse(@saved_object.features)
      @other_object['key']['previously_purchased'] = true
      @new_object = @other_object.to_json
      request.cookies[:prior_purchase] = 'sub'
      get :index
   end

    it 'finds object' do
      expect(assigns(:keyword_object)).to be_nil
    end
  end
end
```

this returns the following error

`Failure/Error: @other_object = JSON.parse(@saved_nanobar.features)`
`TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String`

which makes sense, in a way as I wasn't able to set the value previously_purchased to true.

I also tried

```
context 'object is displayed only to previously purchased' do
  before(:each) do
     @saved_object = create :object
     @saved_object.features['key']['previously_purchased'] = true
     request.cookies[:prior_purchase] = 'sub'
     get :index
  end

  it 'finds object' do
    expect(assigns(:keyword_object)).to be_nil
  end
end
```

`Failure/Error: @saved_object.features['key']['previously_purchased'].to_json = true`
`NoMethodError: undefined method`[ ]' for nil:NilClass`

Which I kind of understand but not well enough to fix my test. I may have left out an end or some other syntax in forming and writing my question, so kindly have patience with those.

This has been blocking me for to long and I'd appreciate any help. I was unable to find resources to help guide me further. If you need me to modify/ clarify my question or need more info, let me know and I'll get right on it.

Comment: Why do you have a file called `object.rb`? `Object` is a core Ruby class and shouldn't have things arbitrarily added to it. Also not clear how JSON factors in here. If you're receiving parameters, Rails will parse them for you. If you're storing things in the database in JSON format you can use `serialize` to handle that for you.

Comment: it's the model and it's not actually named object.rb, I just changed it to make the question as generic as possible. Each Object has column attributes and one of the columns attributes is saved as a JSON object.

Comment: I think you've gone too generic here, it's missing context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `object.features` needs to contain a JSON. Setup your object like this:

```
@saved_object = create(
  :object, features: "{ \"key\": { \"previously_purchased\": true} }"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If a column's saved as JSON, you should be using [`serialize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html), that will take care of all the mess:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :features, JSON
end
```

Then you can manipulate this as any other structure without need for manually de or re serializing:

```
model = MyModel.new
model.features = { key: { previously_purchased: true } }
model.save
```

Then you can do this:

```
def previously_purchased?
  if (self.features)
    !!self.features.dig('key', 'previously_purchased')
  else
    false
  end
end
```

That uses double-negation (`!!`) to force that value as a boolean as well as the Ruby 2.3.1 [`dig`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Hash.html#method-i-dig) method to navigate the hash.

Comment: I like this, it's really clean. I'll refactor my methods in a similar fashion.